# Jquery Cycle - how to create link from anchor

Tags: jquery, cycle, jquery-cycle

I'm using this Jquery:

```
$('#<%=ModuleControl.ModuleContext.ModuleId%>_Rotator div.DNNModuleContent > div.Normal').after('<ul class="RotatorNav">').cycle({
        fx: 'fade', //effect to apply to rotation
        speed: 1000, // speed of the transition (any valid fx speed value) 
        timeout: 5000, // milliseconds between slide transitions (0 to disable auto advance)
        pager: '#<%=ModuleControl.ModuleContext.ModuleId%>_Rotator .RotatorNav', //selector for rotator navigation
        allowPagerClickBubble: true,
        // callback fn that creates a navigation to use as pager anchor 
        pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) {
            return '<li><a href="#">' + slide.title + '</a></li>';
        }
    });
```

And in my bannercontainer I'm using this two lines for specifying the banner and the anchor text:

```
<a title="Twitter" target="_self" href="/Twitter/tabid/86/Default.aspx" re_target="_self">
   <img alt="" src="/portals/0/Images/positie1/header-twitter.png" />
</a>
```

Now I want to have a hyperlink to a specific webpage when clicking the anchor instead of going to that specific banner when clicking.

I think it should be something in the HTML line but I'm not that good, sorry. Someone any help?

Answer (score 0):

An anchor tag **is a link** just specify the url in the `href` attribute.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Can you give me an example because i tried adding a href.

Answer (score 0):

try remove:

```
    pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) {
        return '<li><a href="#">' + slide.title + '</a></li>';
    }
```

Comment: sorry, but that didn't work. It was showed as a link, but there was no action.